# Как сделать автоматическое обновление маркеров?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, google-maps

Здравствуйте! Необходимо, чтобы при добавлении в базу новых координат, на карте маркер выставлялся без обновление страницы. С Ajax ранее не работал (если он для этого), поэтому затрудняюсь реализовать, буду благодарен за помощь.
Страница генерация маркера в базу (из документации гугла):

```
<?php
require("config.php");
function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&apos;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");

header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = $result->fetch()){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'address="'  . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'username="' . parseToXML($row['username']) . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

Страница карты самой карты и маркеров:

```
<?php
 require_once "config.php"
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Los Santos Police Department - 911 Online Map</title>
    <!-- Disallow users to scale this page -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph571/themes/site/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Allow the canvas to use the full height and have no margins */
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- The container the map is rendered in -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Load all javascript -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/SanMap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var description = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
          var username = markers[i].getAttribute("username");
          var point = new SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<strong>911 ВЫЗОВ: </strong>" + username + "<br/>" + 
              "<strong>ЛОКАЦИЯ: </strong>" + address + "<br/>" + "<strong>ОПИСАНИЕ: </strong>" + description;
          var icon = customIcons[username] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}


    var mapType = new SanMapType(2, 5, function (zoom, x, y) {
        return x == -1 && y == -1 
        ? "tiles/map.outer.png" 
        : "tiles/sanandreas." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
    });

    var satType = new SanMapType(2, 3, function (zoom, x, y) {
        return x == -1 && y == -1 
        ? null 
        : "tiles/map." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
    });


    var map = SanMap.createMap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
        {'Карта': mapType, 'Спутник': satType }, 2, null, false, 'Спутник');
</script>
</body>
```

SanMap это карта для игры, которая позволяет работать с игровой картой, а не нашей Земли.

Comment: Можно делать запрос с помощью `ajax`- не изменились ли данные в базе - каждые 5 секунд например. Если изменились - перерисовываем маркеры. Можно пойти в сторону web-socket"ов.

Comment: А вы пробовали удалить маркер и заново поставить ?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=ru

Comment: Чем не устроил ответ?

Comment: Не подходит, я написал какой у меня код и через что я делаю. Добавлять json и менять переменные не стоит.

Comment: Вам показали просто алгоритм действий. Думается готовую программу для Вас никто писать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Для опроса сервера в данном случае можно использовать `EventSource`.

`EventSource` используется для получения серверных событий, без закрытия соединения. Обрабатывается на стороне клиента. Открытое соединение является односторонним, т.е клиент может только слушать входящие сообщения от сервера.

Далее будет приведены листинги кода решающие задачу, а точнее показывающие алгоритм решения.`HTML` разметку включать не буду, там все стандартно.

```
// Создаем функцию обертку, чтобы позже ее вызвать
function eventSource() {

    var event = new EventSource("URI скрипта сервера, который будет вещать");

    // Начинаем слушать события сервера
    event.onmessage = function (message) {

        // Пользовательские данные находятся в поле data.
        var latLng = JSON.parse(message.data);

        latLng.lat = parseFloat(latLng.lat);

        latLng.lng = parseFloat(latLng.lng);

        // Передаем долготу/широту методу, который создает метки
        initMarker(latLng);
    };
}
```

Листинг 2. Работаем с картой.

```
// Делаем map глобальным, чтобы обращатся к нему из других методов
var map;

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

        zoom: 2,
        center: {lat: 37.0902, lng: -95.7129},
        disableDefaultUI: false
    });

    // После того, как инициализирована карта, вызываем нашу обертку, которая будет принимать данные с сервера
    eventSource();
}

function initMarker(latLng) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Листинг 3. Серверная сторона.

```
<?php

// Разрешаем кросс-доменные запросы, иначе попытка соединения клиента провалится
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

// MIME ответа должен быть text/event-stream, иначе попытка соединения клиента провалится
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");


$dbConnect = mysqli_connect("dbServer", "dbUser", "dbPassword", "database");

$id = array();


while (1) {

    // Предположим, что имеем таблицу с id координат, долготой, широтой
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `lat`, `lng` FROM `coordinate`";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $query);

    // Перебор полученных данных
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // Если идентификатора нету в массиве, значит он еще не был выведен
        if (!in_array($row["id"], $id)) {

            // Добавляем в массив, чтобы исключить повторный вывод
            $id[] = $row["id"];

            // Удаляем идентификатор из результирующего ответа клиенту
            unset($row["id"]);

            // Отдаем json клиенту
            echo "data:" . json_encode($row) . "\n\n";
        }
    }

    ob_end_flush();

    flush();

    sleep(5);
}
```

Примеры кода довольно грубые (было бы неплохо сделать нормальную фильтрацию уже показанных координат. Решить проблему с запросом который выводит все содержимое таблицы и т.п), но рабочие. Если открыть карту и добавить данные в базу, то маркер будет отображен без перезагрузки страницы.

Поддержка в браузерах на [неплохом](http://caniuse.com/#search=server-Sent%20Events) уровне, разве что с `IE` не все гладко.

Если требуется двухсторонний обмен, то можно воспользоваться `WebSocket`.

Использовать `Ajax` в данном случае нерационально, так как клиенту необходимо через интервалы времени опрашивать сервер на наличие данных (каждый опрос - новый `http` запрос), он генерирует больше трафика.

[EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventSource) | [Using server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)